# What is sound money? Is it a well-defined concept within economics?

Tags: macroeconomics, money

I see many broad definitions of what 'sound money' is. I also see it used as adjective.

Is there a universal definition, and is the concept ubiquitous within economics?

Comment: Usually when I've seen people use it they seem to mean "gold" without saying "gold". Sometimes they mean "bitcoin" instead. But let's see if there's an actual definition.